# Auto assign Account Teams (without trigger)

Tags: account-teams

I'm investigating what I can do with Account Teams in SF. 
I don't see any automated way to setup what user is assigned to a what type of Account in what Account Team. Except to write a trigger.
What I wanted to do is to create a rule which will assign a user01 as mainUSSales01 to an Accounts with ShippingCountry == "United States". Is it possible without trigger?

Comment: What's the problem with triggers? :(

Comment: Sure. You could use the process builder to do this.

Comment: @sfdcfox, is it powerful enough to check the value of a field of a record, basing on specific value assign a specific user as a specific team member of an account?

Comment: @Martin Lezer, the only problem is maintenance. I'm happy to code everything with Apex (more time spent -> more $ I get), but I try to stick with point & click if possible. I know that Apex can do everything, what I can point & click.

Comment: @AndriiMuzychuk Yes this is what I thought too. Then I couldn't stop having problem with process builders because they are not bulkified...

Answer (score 0):

Process Builder can not insert Account Team Member record.